# must define `submit` to use an `input` block in modals [json-pointer:/view/blocks/0/input]

Tags: slack, slack-commands, slack-block-kit

I am trying to provide a response in View. I have the view ID. This used to work before. Suddenly i started receiving this error.

[ERROR] must define `submit` to use an `input` block in modals [json-pointer:/view/blocks/0/input]"